# How do I select the Max in this query? Help for exam

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

So, I'm going thru a lot of exercises for a final SQL exam I have on thursday and I came across another query I'm having doubts about.

The tables in the exercise are supposed to be from a hotel DB. You have three tables involved:

```
    STAY               ROOM                  ROOM_TYPE
    ===========        ============          ============
PK  ID_STAY        PK  ID_ROOM           PK  ID_ROOM_TYPE
    DAYS_QUANT         ID_ROOM_TYPE  FK      DESCRIPTION
    DATE               PRICE
    ID_ROOM  FK
```

The query they are asking me to do is *"Show all data for the Room that has been rented for the highest amount of days (in total) in 2011, by room type (you have to show ID Room Type and Description)"*

This is the way I solved it, I don't know if it's ok:

```
  SELECT RT.ID_ROOM_TYPE, RT.DESCRIPTON, R.*, SUM(S.DAYS_QUANT)
    FROM STAY S, ROOM R, ROOM_TYPE RT
   WHERE YEAR(S.DATE) = '2011'
GROUP BY RT.ID_ROOM_TYPE, RT.DESCRIPTON, R.*
ORDER BY SUM(S.DAYS_QUANT) DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

So, the first thing I'm not sure about, is that R.* I included. Can I put it like that in a SELECT? Can it also be included like that in a GROUP BY?

The other thing I'm not sure about if I will be allowed to use LIMIT or SELECT TOP 1 statements in the exam. Can anyone think of a way to solve this without using those? like with a MAX() statement or something?

Comment: `LIMIT` isn't ANSI, and only supported on MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite.  `FETCH FIRST # ROWS` is ANSI, but only recently...

Comment: @OMG Ponies So...probably the professor won't let us that in the exam because it has only been added recently to ANSI...well I guess I better found another way to do this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are not allowed to use CTEs so I expanded last part of Steve Kass's answer. You may get desired results without TOP or Limit clauses by comparing total days a room was occupied by max total number of days any room of the same type was occupied. To do so, you would first sum days by room and then, using identical derived table, get maximum of days per room type. Joining the two by room type and days you would isolate most used rooms. Then you join starting tables to show all the data. Unlike TOP or Limit this will produce more records in case of a tie.

P.S. this is NOT tested. I believe it will work, but there might be a typo.

```
select r.*, rt.*, roomDays.TotalDays
from Room r inner join Room_type rt
   on r.id_room_type = rt.id_room_type
   inner join 
      (select id_room, id_room_type, sum(days_quant) TotalDays
      from Stay
         inner join Room
           on Stay.id_room = Room.id_room
      where year(Date) = 2011
      group by id_room, id_room_type) roomDays
   on r.id_room = roomDays.id_room
   inner join 
      (select id_room_type, max(TotalDays) TotalDays
      from 
         (select id_room, id_room_type, sum(days_quant) TotalDays
          from Stay
             inner join Room
               on Stay.id_room = Room.id_room
          where year(Date) = 2011
          group by id_room, id_room_type) roomDaysHelper
      group by id_room_type) roomTypeDays
   on r.id_room_type = roomTypeDays.id_room_type
   and roomDays.TotalDays = roomTypeDays.TotalDays
```

Comment: Thank you for this query! you gave me a good idea on how to do this by creating a "helping table" in the FROM clause.

I posted it as an answer, I would reall appretiate if you can give it a look and tell me if you think is ok!

Comment: Imaginative, but unfortunately it would not work. ALL expects subquery. Besides that, you probably ment id_room instead of id_stay in derived table. By the way, I noticed that you do not put joins in your code. Does your sql engine performs some kind of natural join, or you omit them for brevity?

Comment: Yes, I omited them for brevity. Tx!

Answer (score 1):

```
select r.*, t.*
  from room r
  join room_type t on t.id_room_type = r.id_room_type
 where r.id in
       (select
               (select r.id_room
                  from room r
                  join stay on stay.id_room = r.id_room
                 where year(s.date) = '2011'
                   and r.id_room_type = t.id_room_type
                 group by r.id_room
                 order by sum(s.days_quant) desc
                 limit 1) room_id
          from room_type t)
```

Comment: Great way to do it also, but this way also uses "limit 1". You think there's an easy way to do this without the "Limit" or "Select top" statement?

Answer (score 1):

It's always possible to avoid LIMIT 1 or SELECT TOP. One way is to express the top row as the row for which there is no higher row. WHERE NOT EXISTS expresses the idea of "for which there is no."

One way to think of this is as follows: Select those rooms (along with their total days and type information) for which there is no room of the same type with a greater number of total days. That gives you this query (not carefully proofread):

```
with StayTotals as (
  select
    STAY.ID_ROOM, 
    ROOM_TYPE.ID_ROOM_TYPE,
    ROOM_TYPE.DESCRIPTION,
    SUM(STAY.DAYS_QUANT) AS TotalDays2011
  from STAY join ROOM on STAY.ID_ROOM = ROOM.ID_ROOM
            join ROOM_TYPE on ROOM.ID_ROOM_TYPE = ROOM_TYPE.ID_ROOM_TYPE
  where YEAR(STAY.DATE) = 2011
  group by STAY.ID_ROOM, ROOM_TYPE.ID_ROOM_TYPE, ROOM_TYPE.DESCRIPTION
)
  select *
  from StayTotals as T1
  where not exists (
    select *
    from StayTotals as T2
    where T2.ID_ROOM_TYPE = T1.ID_ROOM_TYPE
    and T2.TotalDays2011 > T1.TotalDays2011
  );
```

If you can't use CTEs (the WITH clause), you can rewrite it using subqueries, but it's awkward.

Ranking functions have been part of the SQL standard for quite a while. If you can use them, this may also work:

```
with StayTotals as (
  select
    STAY.ID_ROOM, 
    ROOM_TYPE.ID_ROOM_TYPE,
    ROOM_TYPE.DESCRIPTION,
    SUM(STAY.DAYS_QUANT) AS TotalDays2011
  from STAY join ROOM on STAY.ID_ROOM = ROOM.ID_ROOM
            join ROOM_TYPE on ROOM.ID_ROOM_TYPE = ROOM_TYPE.ID_ROOM_TYPE
  where YEAR(STAY.DATE) = 2011
  group by STAY.ID_ROOM, ROOM_TYPE.ID_ROOM_TYPE, ROOM_TYPE.DESCRIPTION
), StayTotalsRankedByType as (
  select
    ID_ROOM, 
    ID_ROOM_TYPE,
    DESCRIPTION,
    TotalDays2011,
    RANK() OVER (
      PARTITION BY ID_ROOM_TYPE
      ORDER BY TotalDays2011 DESC
    ) as RankInRoomType
  from StayTotals
)
  select
    ID_ROOM, 
    ID_ROOM_TYPE,
    DESCRIPTION,
    TotalDays2011
  from StayTotalsRankedByType
  where RankInRoomType = 1;
```

Finally, one other way to pull in additional columns to describe the grouped MAX results is to use a "carryalong" sort, which was a handy technique before ranking functions were available. Adam Machanic gives an example [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2008/02/08/who-s-on-first-solving-the-top-per-group-problem-part-1-technique.aspx), and there are useful threads on the topic from Usenet, such as [this one](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.sqlserver.programming/browse_thread/thread/964a4014284ec5b4/548640eb7b357a2?hl=en&q=carry-along%20sort%20kass%20sql#0548640eb7b357a2).

Comment: Wow Steve, this is really great stuff! I really appreatiate the effort you put on this one. Unfortunatelly, I don't think I can use CTEs in my exam since they didn't teach us that and is not part of the program. BUT, you gave me a great idea on how to do it with subqueries. I will try to make something out of it and post it myself as an answer. I would really appreciate if you can later give it a look and tell me what you think. tx again man!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
select room.id_room, room_type.description, room.price
from room inner join room_type 
on room.id_room.type = room_type.id_room_type
where room.room_id = (select room_id from stay
where year (date) = 2011
group by id_room
order by sum (days_quant) desc);
```

Unfortunately, this query (as it is now) doesn't show how for many days the most popular room had been rented. But there's no 'limit 1'!

Comment: I don't think this will work. The subquery (select room_id from...) typically returns more than one value. (There is also no column named room_id)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! with all the ideas you gave me I came up with this, let me know if you think it's ok please!

```
SELECT R.ID_ROOM, R.ID_ROOM_TYPE, T.DESCRIPTION, SUM(S.DAYS_CUANT)
FROM ROOM R, ROOM_TYPE T, STAY S
(SELECT ID_STAY, SUM(S.DAYS_QUANT) TOTALDAYS
 FROM STAY S
 WHERE YEAR(S.DATE) = 2011
 GROUP BY S.ID_STAY) STAYHELPER
WHERE YEAR(S.DATE) = 2011 
GROUP BY R.ID_ROOM, R.ID_ROOM_TYPE, T.DESCRIPTION
HAVING SUM(S.DAYS_QUANT) >= ALL STAYHELPER.TOTALDAYS
```